# Oracle REGEX REPLACE - How to replace quote with backslash quote, newline with space, and blackslash with double blackslash

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle12c

I have some fields that could have the following values:

```
"
\
\n <-- or any possible carriage return
```

I want to replace them with the following:

```
\"
\\
  <-- this represents a space
```

Ideally, I would like to do it in a single pass using `REGEX_REPLACE` or some other method.

I'm currently doing it like the following. It is inefficient because it has to make three passes.

```
SELECT replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        'He\llo " I am \na \string\n pl"eas\ne fi"x me\n,
                        '\',
                        '\\'
                    ),
                    '\n',
                    ' '
                ),
                '"',
                '\"'
            )
FROM DUAL;
```

The output should be

```
He\\llo \" I am \ a \\string\  pl\"eas\ e fi\"x me\
```

Comment: So is that a typo in your "replace with" list? Do you want to replace '\n' with itself as you wrote, or with space?

Comment: @mathguy My bad, I meant for `\n` to be replaced by ` ` a space.

Comment: This is still a bit unclear. Your output follows your existing query. Both contradict your problem description. What you are doing is SEQUENTIAL: FIRST you double up the back slashes, and THEN you replace " with \" and \n with space. So in fact when all is done, you are replacing \n with `'\ ' ` (there is a space after backslash), not just a space.

Comment: Regex operations in Oracle are awfully slow, so, even if you manage to do it in one pass, it will still be slower than your current solution.

Comment: Did you measure that it is inefficient?